# LIMIT не работает в запросе SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Друзья, товарищи, есть запрос :

```
SELECT [name]
      ,[date]
      ,[status]
      ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [date] DESC)
  FROM [script_monitoring].[dbo].[script_status] LIMIT 10
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '10'.
```

Сервак MS SQL и студия (10.50.1600.1) сильнее меня), как побороть этот тандем?
Если есть альтернатива, то укажите направление где искать?

Comment: а какая база данных?

Comment: судя по квадратным скобкам у вас видимо ms sql, он не поддержимает limit, вместо него используется top. Или у вас access тогда не знаю что там с лимитом

Comment: замечу, что альтернативой `limit 0, 10` может быть конструкция `order by X offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only `